# Google Maps API Key Failing, V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I found this was the only place to post this error:

```
{$.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+mapAddresses[x]+'&key=xxxxxx'}
```

The status comes back as request denied.  When I try to load the main map with my key I am given an error about my application being disabled, yet nothing is said of this at the API console.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't add the key, it's not needed anymore

Comment: Without the key I keep getting over limit messages.